# Is there a way to show the % difference of the Grand total column in a Pivot Table?

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table, vlookup, difference

Given the following data:

```
Name    Category Time
James   A        10
Michael A        15
Sarah   A        20
James   B        15
Michael B        20
Sarah   B        30
```

I can then put this data into a Pivot Chart and change the Show Values As to % of Column total:

```
Sum of Time Column Labels
Row Labels  James  Michael  Sarah  Grand Total
A           40%    43%      40%    41%   
B           60%    57%      60%    59%
```

This shows that James spends 40% of his time on Cat A and 60% on Cat B.
Looking at the grand total column I would like to create or show in the pivot table the difference between those values and the individuals.

The values should be as below:

```
     James  Michael  Sarah
A    -1%     2%       -1%
B     1%    -2%        1%
```

This shows for example that Michael spends 2% more time on Category A then the average.

This can be accomplished creating a table with the category and name values as columns and rows, and using vlookup or index match to calculate the corresponding values but I'm wondering if this can be done directly on a Pivot Table so it's more dynamic if I wanted to filter the Categories or Names.

I have also looked at creating a Calculated Field but can't find a way with this method as Calculated fields only calculate each row of chosen fields so they would be no way to calculate the total of Cat A's for say James, against the total of all A's for all names.

---EDIT---

I've found a solution which involved adding a column to the source data. I would still be happier with a method of altering the pivot table itself as this method isn't as dynamic as i'd like when wanting to filter by specific row values.

Given the first table above, I would add a column with the formula as follows:

```
=SUMIFS([Time],[Category],[@Category],[Name],[@Name])/SUMIF([Name],[@Name],[Time])-SUMIF([Category],[@Category],[Time])/SUM([Time])
```

This is with the source data in a table.

This column would then by added to the Values section of the pivot table with Summarise Values By 'Max'.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part:

1. Go to the `Field List` of your Pivot Table
2. Under `Values` Click the drop-down you have there and Click `Value Field Settings`
3. Once here, select `Show Values As` then select `% of Grand Total`

This will show how much each person spends on each task.

For the second part you're trying to see the % difference from average, which you would have to house inside the `Fields, Items, & Sets` part of the ribbon under `Analyze`. Create a calculated field and setup your formula there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Mark S. My question might not have been so clear so I've edited it a little. Perhaps you could take a look and suggest a method for creating a calculated field? I've had a go but can't find anyway that would suggest being able subtract someones total percent change from a grand sum as calculated fields only seem to deal with individual rows from the data source.

Comment: What you're asking, % above average, is a little tricky to do at the high level, but here's a link for it [link](https://excelchamps.com/blog/calculation-in-pivot-table/)

Comment: Thanks, I've tried and failed. It looks like calculated items would only create a single item and so one would have to be done for every name or for every category. I have found a solution but it involved adding a column to the source data. I've edited my question with this method.